# VBA ListBox RemoveItem Unspecified Error

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to call remove item on my listbox, I get '-2147467259 (80004005)' unspecified error.

My rowsource property is blank.  I add the items originally through .additem in a module and I call the code below from the form that the listbox is in:

```
ListBox1.RemoveItem CInt(index)
```

The get the error on that line.

Comment: There not too much of info here. I can safely assume that `index` is not causing the error else you would get a different error message `InValid Argument`. Now the error which you mentioned can be replicated when the rowsource is set. Is it possible that somewhere in the code you are setting the rowsource? Can you put this one line before the `Removeitem` line and tell me what do you get `Msgbox Listbox1.RowSource`

Comment: `MsgBox Listbox1.RowSource` is gives an empty dialog. It have `ListBox1.RowSource = ""` a few lines earlier.

Comment: But did you by any chance set `ListBox1.RowSource` in the design mode?

Comment: In design mode it is empty. Another thing to note is that the row i am trying to delete is selected, will that cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The item you are trying to remove is selected.  Add the following statement prior to attempting to remove the item

```
Listbox1.Selected(index) = false
```

Comment: Selection does not seem to affect this either way for me

Answer (score 0):

`Listbox1.Selected(index) = false` is correct, but remember to replace by an integer variable because the .listindex value disappears after deselection, i.e.:

```
dim mylistindex as integer
With Me.Listvariables
mylistindex = .ListIndex
.Selected(.ListIndex) = False
.RemoveItem (mylistindex)
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your FM20.DLL with the version 15.